# how to get the user entered input

Tags: python, apache

Iam beginner to python started with trying  simple programs and below code is one in that .getting user entered input and printing it.and running this code in local host as http://localhost/cgi-bin/ex3.py
given below code is  my simple python code

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"

import cgi, cgitb 
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()

print ("Enter a file name:")
a = int(input("enter input"))
print (a)
```

but it's giving error as

```
 D:\xampp\cgi-bin\ex3.py in ()
      6 print()
      7 
      8 print ("Enter a file name:")
=>    9 a = int(input("enter input"))
     10 print (a)
a undefined, builtin int = <class 'int'>, builtin input = <built-in function input>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line 
      args = ('EOF when reading a line',) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of EOFError object>
```

Comment: What did you give as user input?

Comment: it's giving error .i can't enter the input

Comment: Why aren't you running Python in the normal way? You won't be able to concentrate on learning Python if you're using some unusual environment that isn't working properly.

Comment: ya i know in command line it will  work properly ...but python running in apache is priority for me .any how i have to learn in this environment only .so if u can plz help.

Comment: If it works fine in the standard environment, you need to use a tag to denote your nonstandard environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your program expects a file name (string) then you don't need to cast to integer.

```
print ("Enter a file name:")
a = input("enter input ")
print (a)
```

This works if you enter a string.

Comment: Then as Bhargav asked: What is your input?

Comment: When i run in  local host after this sentence "Enter a file name: enter input "error messages will come. then were i suppose to be enter input ,if its string or int .